# How does Facebook handle tablets?

Tags: facebook, tablet

I'm developing a Facebook app that has a responsive layout. Sometimes my app has to generate a link for the user. Whenever possible, the links will send the user to a *Page Tab* (when the user is on a desktop) and other times it will link directly to the app (when the user is on a mobile phone).

What is the default behavior for Facebook on tablets? Does it show the mobile site or the desktop site?

Should I use the *mobile* or *desktop* version of my app on tablets?

---

**Update**: *In response to BBog's question in the comments:*
My app prefers the desktop version because it includes a Like-gate. If the user experience is good for a tablet to view the app in a page tab (which is only available on www.facebook.com ie non-mobile), then that is preferred because the like button will be displayed at the top of the page, above the app's iframe. In contrast, the mobile version of the app requires that the user click a link that takes them to the (mobile) facebook page which they must like to un-gate the app. It adds an extra step for the user and requires that they navigate away from the app for a moment. Users might be discouraged by this extra step and decide not to enter the gate.

Comment: Certain tablets gets redirected m.facebook.com and some to www.facebook.com. Best bet, check [Facebook mobile web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/), there is a section on "User Agent" where it may of help.

Comment: Thanks, detecting the user agent is not a problem. However, knowing what to show when a tablet is detected is my main issue. However, you gave me the idea of checking the referrer to see if the user came from www.facebook... or m.facebook...

Comment: It's been almost a year since I last dealt with Facebook's API, so I can't give you a straight answer to your question, but as an alternate solution, why don't you try to detect if your user has a touch enabled device? If this is true, you redirect him to the mobile app, otherwise, to the desktop version. I don't know exactly what is different in your mobile version, but if it's optimized for touch devices / 3G speed connection, wouldn't you prefer to show all the tablets the mobile version and, eventually, give them the option to switch to the desktop version?

Comment: If this seems like a reasonable solution to you, I can give you more info on what we use to detect tablets. If I misunderstood your problem, I apologize

Comment: see my response in the update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a concrete answer, I ended up detected the user's referral on the first page access. Then if `www.facebook.com` is in the url, I go to desktop. Otherwise I go to mobile..

```
 if ($detect->isTablet()) {
  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION["tabletAsMobile"]))
    $_SESSION["tabletAsMobile"] = (stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'www.facebook.com')===true):'0':'1';
  }

  $useMobileLinks = ($detect->isMobile() || ($detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION["tabletAsMobile"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android tablets - Honestly, it depends on how you want Facebook to handle it. If you look at the android native app linking wiki - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/, Facebook provides you the option to choose the user experience. The facebook native android app itself treats tablets like mobile phones. It would be ideal if your app is compatible with tablets, and then you can enable deep-linking which will let the user view the content inside of your app. 
For iOS, it's handled from within the iOS bundle id.

Comment: thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for. This is not a native app.